# Create Instance & Invoke static Main of an assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, invoke, createinstance

I'm having a problem creating an instance of an assembly of a static void Main().

Heres is the code of the Assembly (.NET Exe)

```
namespace Test
{ 
    internal static class Program
    {

        [STAThread]
        private static void Main(string[] args)
```

And here is the launcher code : 
bin is an array of bytes which contains my assembly read from the file.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(bin); 
MethodInfo method = asm.EntryPoint;
object obj = asm.CreateInstance(method.ToString());
method.Invoke(obj, null);
```

obj is always null and Invoke throws exception because of parameter mismatch.

Answer (score 7):

The entry point of an executable is a method, and methods don't have instances, classes do.

So if you intend to create an instance of the `Main` class, you should get the `DeclaringType` of the method:

```
object obj = asm.CreateInstance(method.DeclaringType.ToString());
```

But in this case that is useless, since a static method doesn't have an instance it is called on, so omitting the instance is all you have to do:

```
method.Invoke(null, null);
```

If you want to invoke the method with parameters, make sure you make one entry per argument in the object array:

```
object[] parameters = new object[] { new string[] { "","" } };
method.Invoke(null, parameters);
```

Comment: If I call

method.Invoke(null, null);
it throws an exception : parameter count mismatch

If I call

object[] args = { new string[] { "", "" } };
method.Invoke(null, args);
it throws : target of an invocation has caused an exception.

Comment: The last error means something goed wrong at the other end. Debug that program.

Answer (score 4):

You can´t create an instance of a method, just call it:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(bin); 
MethodInfo method = asm.EntryPoint;
method.Invoke(null, new[] { myParams });
```

As `main` is a static method you don´t need an instance of your class. This is why the first argument to `Invoke` is `null`. The second argument however is the list of params passed to `main`, so in your case it´s something like `new object[] { new string[] { "firstArg", "secondArg" } }` or if you don´t provide any args simply `null`.

Comment: But it doesnt work with argument null. It get exception : parameter count mismatch